# Migrating rewrite rules under subdirectory from Apache to IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, rewrite, url, iis-8.5

In the old Apache hosting, we had the following `.htaccess` file inside `public_html/adm`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /adm/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is supposed to redirect every url after the `adm` subdir to the `/adm/index.php` file, if the path does not exist. And works just fine.

Then I migrated this website to IIS (v8.5), and using the "Import Rules..." tool, I attempted to achieve the same effect, but at first it was messing with urls other than those under the `/adm` path. In an attempt to overcome this, I changed the original `.htaccess` file slightly, like below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond adm/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond adm/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule adm/. /adm/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The resulting IIS rules are as follows:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="adm/." ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="adm/{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" pattern="" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                <add input="adm/{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" pattern="" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/adm/index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

At first it seemed to work(1), but I quickly noticed that valid paths are being redirected as well(2). **How can to make it work properly?**

1. `http://example.com/aaaa` returns 404 error, and `http://example.com/adm/aaaa` returns the contents of `http://example.com/adm/index.php` (this is expected).
2. `http://example.com/adm/images/logo.png`, which is a valid path, returns the contents of the index.php file (this is mistaken).

This is the result of the Rewrite Rules from the `web.config` file.
[image: view of iis rewrite rules]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Match Conditions are not being met. This is due to the (mistaken) addition of `adm/` in front of them.

The value of the `REQUEST_FILENAME` [server variable](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1698-understanding-the-iis-mod-rewrite-server-variables.htm) is the full path, on the filesystem, of the file (or directory) being requested. In my specific test case:

*Request URL:* `http://example.com/adm/images/logo.png`
*{REQUEST_FILENAME}*: `F:\IIS\example.com\adm\assets\img\logo.png`

For obvious reasons, appending `adm/` in front of that value will make it into a non-valid filesystem path, and as a result, the rewrite rule will be enforced even for valid files/directories. The solution is simple:

[image: correct rewrite rules]

The filtering pattern can also be updated to valid regex syntax, even if out of perfectionism, since the previous step alone was enough to fix the problem at hand.

[image: new regex syntax]

Updated rules for the `web.config` file as follows.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(adm\/).*" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" pattern="" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" pattern="" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/adm/index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex isn't correct. It doesn't match the entire value after the `/`

The results of `adm/.` returns a match for `adm/i`. So it is correct in assuming that the file does not exist.

You're regex should be: `adm/.*`

When creating a rule in IIS GUI, hit the `Test Pattern` button in the `Match URL` section to see the results.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to apply to my question. I don't mention `css/.` anywhere. Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing my own site and stupidly forgot to change the values. I've edited the response.

Comment: Still, this answer is not fully helpful. The pattern is used for capturing/qualifying the URL, not for testing it against the condition(s). But thanks for pointing that out. I'll update my pattern to proper regex syntax.